# XeLaTex fontspec crash on Texmaker [LaTeX error: "kernel/invalid-variant"]

Tags: xetex, fontspec

when I compile:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
Hallo
\end{document}
```

on Texmaker 5.0.2 with XeLaTex and Commandline:

```
xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex
```

I get the following Error-Message:

```
! LaTeX error: "kernel/invalid-variant"
! Variant form 'e' invalid for base form '\tl_if_empty_p:n'.
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
```

Version:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.6960 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.2.2) 16 FEB 2019 23:07
```

I already reinstall the fontspec package.

My base requirement was to bound in Amatic RC Regular to LaTeX (font with hand written style), but I have to admit that I failed miserably.

Maybe some of you know the error?

Log-File:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (MiKTeX 2.9.6960 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2019.2.16)  17 FEB 2019 07:15
entering extended mode
**./Amatic.tex
(Amatic.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script document class (article)
(C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrkbase.sty
Package: scrkbase 2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent b
asics and keyval usage)

(C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrbase.sty
Package: scrbase 2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)

(D:\Installed\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrlfile.sty
Package: scrlfile 2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
)))
(C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\tocbasic.sty
Package: tocbasic 2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
\scr@dte@tocline@numberwidth=\skip41
\scr@dte@tocline@numbox=\box27
)
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `toc'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `toc' on input line 133.
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lof'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lof' on input line 135.
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lot'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lot' on input line 136.
Class scrartcl Info: File `scrsize11pt.clo' used instead of
(scrartcl)           file `scrsize11.clo' to setup font sizes on input line 208
0.

(C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrsize11pt.c
lo
File: scrsize11pt.clo 2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt
)
)
(C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\typearea.sty
Package: typearea 2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script package (type area)
\ta@bcor=\skip42
\ta@div=\count80
\ta@hblk=\skip43
\ta@vblk=\skip44
\ta@temp=\skip45
\footheight=\skip46
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 10
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 418.25555pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -6%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 17.3562pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = 17.3562pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 595.80026pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -25.16531pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 17.0pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 20.40001pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 11.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 47.6pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 13.6pt
(typearea)              on input line 1686.
)
\c@part=\count81
\c@section=\count82
\c@subsection=\count83
\c@subsubsection=\count84
\c@paragraph=\count85
\c@subparagraph=\count86
\scr@dte@part@maxnumwidth=\skip47
\scr@dte@section@maxnumwidth=\skip48
\scr@dte@subsection@maxnumwidth=\skip49
\scr@dte@subsubsection@maxnumwidth=\skip50
\scr@dte@paragraph@maxnumwidth=\skip51
\scr@dte@subparagraph@maxnumwidth=\skip52
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textsubscript on input line 4161.
\abovecaptionskip=\skip53
\belowcaptionskip=\skip54
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box28
\c@figure=\count87
\c@table=\count88
Class scrartcl Info: Redefining `\numberline' on input line 5319.
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (D:\Installed\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.sty
(C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse.
sty (C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2018/03/05 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2018/03/05 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count89
\l_tmpa_int=\count90
\l_tmpb_int=\count91
\g_tmpa_int=\count92
\g_tmpb_int=\count93
\g__intarray_font_int=\count94
\g__prg_map_int=\count95
\c_log_iow=\count96
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count97
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count98
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count99
\l__iow_indent_int=\count100
\c_zero_dim=\dimen103
\c_max_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
\c_zero_skip=\skip55
\c_max_skip=\skip56
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip57
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip58
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip59
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip60
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
\l_keys_choice_int=\count101
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count102
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count103
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count104
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count105
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count106
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count107
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count108
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count109
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count110
\c__fp_rand_size_int=\count111
\c__fp_rand_four_int=\count112
\c__fp_rand_eight_int=\count113
\l__sort_length_int=\count114
\l__sort_min_int=\count115
\l__sort_top_int=\count116
\l__sort_max_int=\count117
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count118
\l__sort_block_int=\count119
\l__sort_begin_int=\count120
\l__sort_end_int=\count121
\l__sort_A_int=\count122
\l__sort_B_int=\count123
\l__sort_C_int=\count124
\l__tl_build_start_index_int=\count125
\l__tl_build_index_int=\count126
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count127
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count128
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count129
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count130
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count131
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count132
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count133
\l__regex_balance_int=\count134
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count135
\l__regex_mode_int=\count136
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count137
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count138
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count139
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count140
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count141
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count142
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count143
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count144
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count145
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count146
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count147
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count148
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count149
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count150
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count151
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count152
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count153
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count154
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count155
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count156
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count157
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count158
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count159
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count160
\l__regex_step_int=\count161
\l__regex_min_active_int=\count162
\l__regex_max_active_int=\count163
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count164
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count165
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count166
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count167
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count168
\g__regex_trace_regex_int=\count169
\c_empty_box=\box29
\l_tmpa_box=\box30
\l_tmpb_box=\box31
\g_tmpa_box=\box32
\g_tmpb_box=\box33
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen109
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen110
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen111
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen112
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen113
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen114
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen115
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen116
\l__box_internal_box=\box34
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box35
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen117
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen118
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen119
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen120
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen121
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen122
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen123
\c_empty_coffin=\box36
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box37
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box38
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box39
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box40
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box41
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box42
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box43
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen124
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen125
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen126
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen133
)
(C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\l3xdvipdfmx.def
File: l3xdvidpfmx.def 2017/03/18 v L3 Experimental driver: xdvipdfmx
\g__driver_image_int=\count170
))
Package: xparse 2018/02/21 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count171
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count172
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count173
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count174
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count175
)
Package: fontspec 2019/01/25 v2.7a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 (D:\Installed\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec-xetex.sty
Package: fontspec-xetex 2019/01/25 v2.7a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count176
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count177
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count178
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count179
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count180
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count181
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count182
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count183
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count184
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count185
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count186
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen134
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen135
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen136
\g__file_internal_ior=\read1

(D:\Installed\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package

(D:\Installed\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\tuenc.def
File: tuenc.def 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding TU on input line 82.
))

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "kernel/invalid-variant"
! 
! Variant form 'e' invalid for base form '\tl_if_empty_p:n'.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.508 \cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_empty_p:n {e}

|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| This is a coding error.
| 
| LaTeX has been asked to create a variant of the function '\tl_if_empty_p:n'
| with a signature starting with 'e', but cannot change an argument from type
| 'n' to type 'e'.
|...............................................

.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \fontspec with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 584.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmainfont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 589.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setsansfont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 594.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmonofont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 599.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathrm with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 603.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setboldmathrm with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 607.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathsf with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 611.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathtt with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 615.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setromanfont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 619.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfamily with sig. 'mO{}mO{}' on line 623.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \renewfontfamily with sig. 'mO{}mO{}' on line 627.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setfontfamily with sig. 'mO{}mO{}' on line 631.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontface with sig. 'mO{}mO{}' on line 635.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \defaultfontfeatures with sig. 't+om' on line 642.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \addfontfeatures with sig. 'm' on line 646.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \addfontfeature with sig. 'm' on line 650.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 654.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newAATfeature with sig. 'mmmm' on line 658.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newopentypefeature with sig. 'mmm' on line 662.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newICUfeature with sig. 'mmm' on line 666.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 670.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeatureoption with sig. 'mmm' on line 674.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontscript with sig. 'mm' on line 678.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontlanguage with sig. 'mm' on line 682.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareFontExtensions with sig. 'm' on line 686.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \IfFontFeatureActiveTF with sig. 'mmm' on line 690.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \liningnums with sig. 'm' on line 701.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingCommand with sig. 'mO{}m' on line 3761.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingAccent with sig. 'mm' on line 3767.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingSymbol with sig. 'mm' on line 3773.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingComposite with sig. 'mmm' on line 3779.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingCompositeCommand with sig. 'mmm' on line 3785.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareUnicodeEncoding with sig. 'mm' on line 3810.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \UndeclareSymbol with sig. 'm' on line 3816.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \UndeclareAccent with sig. 'm' on line 3822.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \UndeclareCommand with sig. 'm' on line 3828.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \UndeclareComposite with sig. 'mm' on line 3835.
.................................................
(D:\Installed\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.cfg)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 4017.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 4022.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 4027.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 4032.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 4062.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \emph on input line 4087.
)) (Amatic.aux)
\openout1 = `Amatic.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/redefine-command"
. 
. Redefining command \oldstylenums with sig. 'm' on line 4.
.................................................
.................................................
. fontspec info: "setup-math"
. 
. Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid this).
.................................................
\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/lmr/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/bx/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/bx/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/lmr/bx/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/bx/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/bx/n on input line 4.
 [1

]
(Amatic.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 12420 strings out of 427748
 289278 string characters out of 3152492
 457168 words of memory out of 3000000
 16489 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 530296 words of font info for 25 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1328 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 46i,6n,51p,10391b,233s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on Amatic.pdf (1 page).
```

Comment: I just add \listfiles to your MWE. and get this log http://ix.io/1BeD. No error.

Comment: This normally means that part of your tex system is not up-to-date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit in your case is that your packages are not all of them up to date. Your used KOMA-Script is older than mine, but important for you is that your `expl3-code.tex`

```
(C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2018/03/05 L3 programming layer (code)
               ^^^^^^^^^^
```

is too old. There was a bug in it. You need to update!

Mine is

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
Package: expl3 2019-01-28 L3 programming layer (code)
```

Open MiKTeX Console, and update as admin and user (if you have an admin installation; only as user, if you have a user installation).

If clicking and searching for "Updates" does not help, click on "Packages" and check `l3kernel` to be up to date:

[image: MiKTeX Console]

1. Enter `l3kernel` where the red arrow points to
2. click on the sign in the red circle marked with 2 (that activates a selection to show only entrys with `l3kernel`
3. Click on the + sign (red circle marked with 3) to activate the package update.

Comment: thanks for your advice! The fact that my l3kernel is not uptodate is really weird, because I only installed for two days to run XeLaTeX. So I reinstalled it, but the Log-Line stay the same: Package: expl3 2018/03/05 L3 programming layer (loader). IS there a other way to update?

Comment: Do you have an admin installation or a user installation? If you have a admin installation it **is important you run the MiKTeX Console as admin and user** to update.

Comment: thanks for bold typing your last comment. You was totally right and me blind as hell. I really can't imagine that admin und user mode have different state of updates. I will not questioning that. I am sorry for wasting your time, and thanks a lot for your patient help.